# "fread" reads wrong values when it's reading numbers

Tags: c, file, fread

Let's say I have a file:

*file.in*:

```
3 3
```

and I want to read the 2 numbers that are written in it with `fread`, so I write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int buffer[3] = {0}; // 3 items bcs it also reads the space between the "3"s
    FILE* f = fopen("file.in", "r");

    fread(buffer, 3, 4, f);

    printf("%d %d", buffer[0], buffer[2]);
}
```

I think the output should be `3 3`, but I am getting somethink like `17?????? 17??????`. But if I make `int buffer[3] = {0};` to `char buffer[3] = {'\0'};` it works fine

---

Any attemt to help is appreciated

Comment: Wait, your file has ascii characters representing decimal numbers? Or it has raw binary signed 32-bit values?

Comment: You are reading binary, but open the file as ascii. Is you data written as binary or as ascii?

Comment: @Devolus how to I ckeck if it is written n binary or ascii?

Comment: In your `fopen` call you use currently `"r"`. For a binary file it should be `"rb"`. Same when you wrote the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fread()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) is for reading the byte stream from the files. `3 3` is represented using 3bytes `0x33 0x20 0x33` if ASCII is used, so `fread(buffer, 3, 4, f);` (read 12 bytes) is not for reading this.

If you want to store the bytes in `int`, you should use [`fgetc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int buffer[3] = {0}; // 3 items bcs it also reads the space between the "3"s
    FILE* f = fopen("file.in", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        buffer[i] = fgetc(f);
    }

    printf("%c %c", buffer[0], buffer[2]); // use %c instead of %d to print the characters corresponding to the character codes
}
```

Comment: I thought that `fgetc` returns `char`, for example in this case that it would return `'3'`, `' '`,  `'3'`

Comment: @platinoob_ The returned things are correct, but [`fgetc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) returns `int`.

Comment: I tried it and it's giving me `char`s, I need these numbers to do certain stuff later in the actual program, like make a matrix (`char* matrix = (char*)calloc(buffer[0], 1); for (int i = 0; i < buffer[0]; i++) {matrix[i] = (char*)calloc(buffer[2], 1);}`), and what if instead of `3 3`, *file.in* is `123 132`?

Comment: @platinoob_ You should use `fscanf()` or parse the file by yourself.

Comment: actually I have finished the program and that's what I did in the end, it's just that bcs I read somewhere that `fread` is faster I am just examining the case of using `fread`

Comment: Hopefully you understand this by now, but: `fread` performs a *completely* different task than `fscanf`, so it doesn't matter if `fread` is faster.  A bullet is faster than a screwdriver, but you can't use a bullet to drive screws.

Comment: Later in the file there are single characters that my program needs to read, they don't even have space between them, for these, should I use `fread` or `fgetc` (I used `fgetc`)?

Comment: @platinoob_ It will depend on the design. Both can be used to read characters. `fread` can read multiple characters by one function call, so it may be efficient. `fscanf()` also can be used to read characters. (`%c` specifier is for reading one character)